# Error when sending http request to sharepoint "Not well formatted JSON stream. clientRequestId"

Tags: development, sharepoint-rest-api, power-automate

We have this "Send http request to SharePoint" >> to create a sharing link for specific users

[image]

but this is raising this error:-

```
{

  "status": 400,

  "message": "Not well formatted JSON stream.\r\nclientRequestId: cbad5391-8112-46c4-b4a0-8eb4da1fd764\r\nserviceRequestId: 064ab2a0-0006-6000-94ac-5a489f578214",

  "source": "https://******.sharepoint.com/sites/Certification/_api/web/Lists('***')/GetItemByID('16')/Sharelink",

  "errors": [

    "-1",

    "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException"

  ]

}
```

here is sample of the request body i am sending:-

```
{ "request":{
"createLink":true, "peoplePickerInput":"[ { "Key":"**@yahoo.com", "IsResolved":false },{ "Key":"***@gmail.com", "IsResolved":false } ]",
"settings":{
"linkKind":6,
"password':"",
"updatePassword": false,
"role":1,
"restrictShareMembership":true,
"scope":2
}
}
}
```

so what could be causing the erro i am getting? Thanks